# After migrating a website with MYSQL DB the website (PHP) displays an error. what does the error mean?

Tags: php, error-handling, web, syntax-error

I am still pretty new to everything. So if you need any more information, let me know.

What I did so far :

I copied a website from one ubuntu 10.10 server to another 12.04 ubuntu server.
I also backupped and restored the MYSQL Database.
I configurated apache2 (which is right now just locally) to display my page.
I have 3 Pages on 3 ports, the other pages work, so I probably configurated apache2 correctly.
At first i just saw a blank page, when I tried to contact my website, so I switched on the error screens.

This is what appears , I replaced the websitename to xxxx :

```
 Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/index.php on line 11
 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php 
 on line 311 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php 
 on line 385 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php
  on line 923 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX/Server.php
   on line 161 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX.php
    on line 612 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX/Serializer/JSON.php 
    on line 46 Warning: include_once(../pear/Net/Socket.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Net/SMTP.php 
    on line 25 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../pear/Net/Socket.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
    in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 25 Warning: include_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
     /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 65 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PEAR.php' for inclusion
      (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 65 Warning:
       include_once(../pear/Mail/mimePart.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php 
       on line 75 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../pear/Mail/mimePart.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
        in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 75 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
        /data/xxxx/www/pear/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php on line 180 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference 
        is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php on line 189 Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference
         has been deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/modules/statistics/frontend.class.php on line 16 Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference 
         has been deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/modules/users/frontend.class.php on line 19 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new 
         by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB/common.php on line 958 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by
          reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB/common.php on line 1150 Notice: DB Error: connect failed in 
          /data/xxxx/www/classes/registry.class.php on line 70
```

the only thing I understand here is : Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)

it seems that some data was not copied correctly. 
How to check the excat size of the folder and subfolders? so I can compare at least :) 
Thanks in advance.

ANY HELP will be upvoted very fast.

Comment: dude, your now running on a updated version of php many of your old functions are now deprecated. and your also missing references to some files.

Comment: Just like the error messages say, you have code that is obsolete. You need to go to each of those errors (you're told exactly where they are) and correct them. Google the error messages and you will be told *exactly* how to fix them.

Comment: You can also check the depricated function page which will also tell you what to move out to

Comment: `Error: connect failed in /data/xxxx/www/classes/registry.class.php on line 70`: probably a good start?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected...but I was hoping for something else. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, since it's not my website i migrated there. Would you recommend to download old version of php on my new server and make it run ? Or is there a way to have 2 versions of php. I mean is there any "smart" solution which keeps me away from editing all the php?

Comment: There are no smart solutions beside keeping the code updated

Comment: OKAY, Since all of this are warnings, and the DB ERROR is coded in the page, if he can't grab the DB correctly. So why isn't anything displayed :/.  Btw. Every page displays THIS error. i mean subpages. is that the usual way? thanks

Answer (score 2):

> set_magic_quotes_runtime()

Just get rid of this function call.

> Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in

Just get rid of & sign in the statement.

> Warning: include_once(PEAR.php):

You have to install PEAR

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have changed PHP versions. Very likely that your `Ubuntu 10.10` box was running `PHP 5.2.x` or `PHP 5.3.x` and now your `Ubuntu 12.04` box is running `PHP 5.4.x` or `PHP 5.5.x` (low chance).

You have two real solutions:

**Update your code (recommended)**

Go in line-by-line and update your code and correct the errors, you should be able to research those errors individually and use http://php.net/ as a resource.

**Downgrade your php/mysql version**

You can check your old PHP version on the Ubuntu 10.10 box by running the following command in terminal: `php -v`; then do the same command on your 12.04 box to see what you have upgraded to.

There is plenty of documentation out there for changing PHP versions on Linux, so I empower you to do that research.

You will also want to copy your php.ini configuration over to the new install also--it's very likely you have some ancient configurations by the looks of your `magic_quotes` errors.

Comment: I just checked my version. 12.04 has 5.3.10 and old server 10.10 ubuntu has : 5.3.3    what do you recommend me to do ? work through all the shit or try to make an old version of php run on new server?

Comment: @RayofCommand Hmm... thats not a significant version change. I would compare your php.ini files. Makes me wonder if you've just had strict error notices turned off all this time along with some other ancient configurations.

Comment: That's the error reporting which i found in the index.php before I addet the display_errors;  :
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_PARSE /*| E_WARNING*/);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: i copied the old ini file to new server, still the same.

Comment: @RayofCommand all of the `deprecated` errors are warnings only, the functionality will still exist. Errors like: `Warning: include_once(../pear/Net/Socket.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Net/SMTP.php` mean that your missing files--they were likely in your server PATH. You can simply disable `E_STRICT ^ E_WARNING` error reporting to turn of deprecation notices.